# How to search for multiple synonyms?

Tags: synonyms, data

I have a database with 2 tables : **products**, and **synonyms**.
When a user type one or several words to search in the **products.description** field, I would like to search for all the synonyms/substitutions as well.

The **synonyms** table is basic, and have to columns : **word1** and **word2**.
Example of its content :

- chiptune <-> 8bit
- lofi <-> lo-fi
- lo-fi <-> 8bit

In SQL, How can I present to the user results feturing the word "**lofi**" when he type "**chiptune**"?
What I am trying to achieve is a "loop between synonyms", in both ways.

Thank you if you have some thoughts.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You can use a recursive CTE to travers the chain. You may instead concider storing groups of synonyms.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid problems with cycles in your graph, I would suggest that you re-design your structure to:

```
CREATE TABLE products
( product_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
);

CREATE TABLE synonym_groups
( synonym_group_id ... NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, ...
);

CREATE TABLE synonym_group_products
( synonym_group_id ... NOT NULL
, product_id NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY  -- A product belongs to exactly one group 
,     CONSTRAINT ... 
      FOREIGN KEY (synonym_group_id)
          REFERENCES synonym_groups (synonym_group_id)
,     CONSTRAINT ... 
      FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
          REFERENCES products (product_id)
);
```

I created a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5fb555dff269ed94f00b8c99ae3e2818), I just used integer for keys since I don't know what identifies your entities. To get the synonyms of chiptune:

```
select p2.*
FROM products p1
JOIN synonym_group_products sgp1
    ON p1.product_id = sgp1.product_id
JOIN synonym_group_products sgp2
    ON sgp1.synonym_group_id = sgp2.synonym_group_id
JOIN products p2
    ON sgp2.product_id = p2.product_id
WHERE p1.product_name = 'chiptune'
  AND p1.product_id <> p2.product_id;
```